# UWP HttpClient Authorization from PHP example

Tags: c#, php, http, web, uwp

I am using `HttpClient` to get http content from url. Some one provide me with example in `php` for service that i should use with username and password:

```
$user = "testUser";
$passwd = "testPassword";
$url = "testurl";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$user:$passwd");
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

How to convert that into c# code and provide it with username and password?

Now my code looks like this, but doesn't help:

```
string url = "my url";
var result = string.Empty;
var client = new HttpClient();
var msg = await client.GetAsync(url);
if (msg.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var data = await msg.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    result = encoding.GetString(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
    Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(String.Format("{0}:{1}", "user", "pass"))));
```

Actually this line of code does work nice